# EF is including Child's reference back to Parent's siblings

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, include

I'm querying my Deliveries and including one of it's property (Material Type) and it's returning everything good except that my Material Type has a list of Deliveries. Therefore its returning Delivery siblings.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Delivery
{
    public int DeliveryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    ...
    public int MaterialTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual MaterialType MaterialType { get; set; }
}

public class MaterialType
{
    public int MaterialTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Delivery> Deliveries { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my deliveries query by date range

```
var deliveries = DataStore.Filter<Delivery>(i =>
                 i.DeliveryDate >= startDate && i.DeliveryDate < endDate
                 ,new string[] { "MaterialType" }) // Includes
                 .OrderByDescending(i => i.DeliveryDate).ToList();

public virtual IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string[] includes = null) where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> set = dbContext.Set<T>();
    if (includes != null && includes.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            set = set.Include(include);
        }
    }
    return set.Where<T>(predicate).AsQueryable<T>();
}
```

Here are the results that I'm getting back from the query and the Delivery.MaterialType.Delivery is being populated back with the siblings of the original Delivery.

```
[{
    "DeliveryId": 1,
    "DeliveryDate": "2017-05-22",
    "MaterialTypeId": 2,
    "MaterialType": {
        "MaterialTypeId": 2,
        "Name": "Bulk",
        "Deliveries": [{
            "DeliveryId": 2,
            "DeliveryDate": "2017-05-22",
            "MaterialTypeId": 2,
        },
        {
            "DeliveryId": 3,
            "DeliveryDate": "2017-05-22",
            "MaterialTypeId": 2,
        }]
    }
}]
```

Lazy loading is set to disabled.

```
dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Is there any way to prevent MaterialTypes from populating Deliveries?

Comment: This is how eager loading (`Include`) works (although shouldn't include the siblings). In your case, the collection could have been populated by *lazy loading* (it's `virtual` as I see).

Comment: @IvanStoev What I have noticed is that the deliveries under the MaterialType are driven by the filter i have above (Date range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure Lazy loading is at fault here, rather this might have to do something with the auto-wiring up of relationships.

So let's say that you have Delivery A with Material Type A, and Delivery B with Material Type A also. If you issue a query for the deliveries and include the material type, then the list of deliveries in Material Type A will contain both Delivery A and Delivery B, because they get loaded into the context as the result of the query anyways.

Disabling lazy loading only tells EF not to load any entities when accessing the property, but it does not say anything about fixing up the relationships between entities that are already in the context.

Same situation can happen if you issue multiple queries using the same DbContext object: once a query is run and the results are materialized, the objects are in the context. So if you issue another query with the same context where one of the resulting objects has a reference to the previously loaded entity, the navigation properties are populated automatically based on the objects that are in the context.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to avoid those properties? I have a solution where I'm iterating through the items and clearing out the values.

Comment: Nice suggestion!  I completely forgot about entity relationship fixups.

Comment: @Miguel To be honest, I'm not sure. You could add the `AsNoTracking()` method call to the query, but that could only work if the problem arises from multiple queries ; if the entities that are fixed-up are materialized as a result of one single query, I'm not sure if it could work (to be honest not sure if it solves the problem at all).  You could also try setting the `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` property of the context to false, but again, not sure if that actually solves the problem (definitely not if you add new entities to the context too), but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The object you are serializing has Lazy Loading enabled, so it is populating all the properties.  Disable Lazy loading like this before your query:

```
DataStore.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Thanks, for your response! I already have the lazy loading property set to false. Updated my question with that bit of info.

Comment: It should not be doing what you are claiming if Lazy Loading has been disabled.  Throw some debugging code to make sure it that is actually disabled, and that DataStore is using the same dbContext that has the Lazy Loading disabled.  You could try removing the `virtual` keyword from your models, that should also signal to EF that you don't want lazy loading.

Comment: Just verified that lazy loading is set to false. I also gave removing the virtual keyword and still encountering the same issue.